# How to recursively call a closure that is stored in an Arc<Mutex<_>>?

Tags: recursion, rust, reference-counting

I’m trying to transpile a dynamic language into Rust and closures are the most difficult part to implement.

I've tried  using a `Arc<Mutex<dyn FnMut>>`, but it doesn't support recursion.

```rust
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};

type Data = Arc<DataUnpack>;
enum DataUnpack {
    Number(f64),
    Function(Box<Mutex<FnMut(Vec<Data>) -> Data>>),
}

fn call(f: Data, args: Vec<Data>) -> Data {
    if let DataUnpack::Function(v) = &*f {
        let f = &mut *v.lock().unwrap();
        f(args)
    } else {
        panic!("TYPE ERR")
    }
}

fn lambda(f: Box<FnMut(Vec<Data>) -> Data>) -> Data {
    Arc::new(DataUnpack::Function(Box::new(Mutex::new(Box::leak(f)))))
}

fn main() {
    let f: Arc<Mutex<Data>> = Arc::new(Mutex::new(Arc::new(DataUnpack::Number(0.0))));
    *f.lock().unwrap() = {
        let f = f.clone();
        lambda(Box::new(move |xs| {
            println!("Ha");
            call(f.lock().unwrap().clone(), xs.clone())
        }))
    };
    call(f.lock().unwrap().clone(), vec![]);
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a30bef46414614a775a1002aecabb564)

It shows one `Ha` and then stops. Where am I wrong?

Comment: You seem be attempting to lock the mutex twice at the same time, which creates a deadlock. Why are you doing that? Why do you leak the `Box`? Why do you set `f` in main to a number and then overwrite it?

Comment: `Box::leak` seems unnecessary here. Actually, the whole inner `Box` does. [This appears to do the same thing](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ae83edac29242e00b61c166b439423b5) (which is to say, it deadlocks).

Comment: I bet the `Box::leak` was a workaround for `Box<dyn FnMut...>` not implementing `FnMut` in a version of Rust prior to 1.35. Although why the `Box` is there at all, I'm not sure.